# Receive automated emails from new users on Parse

Tags: parse-platform, mailchimp

I built a mobile app using parse.com. Currently, when a new user signs up, their info is being stored in the parse database.

However, when a new user signs up for the app, I'd like to receive an email directly from the user. For example, Jane Smith signs up as janexyz@yahoo.com - I'd like to receive an email to my inbox from janexyz@yahoo.com

The reason why I want to do this is so that I can add a new user to my Mailchimp database. I was planning on using this:
https://zapier.com/zapbook/zaps/1428/add-new-email-data-to-a-mailchimp-list/

Is there something I can do on Parse to enable this? Ideally it doesn't require any coding.

Comment: I sure hope Parse.com doesn't allow you to send out emails from other people's email accounts.

Answer (score 1):

It makes much more sense to add the user directly from the app itself.  That way you have an up to date version without having to go through the manual steps involved in that program you linked to.

Mailchimp has an API which is documented here: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com

It looks like the `listBatchSubscribe` method will do what you need. ([docs](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/rtfm/listbatchsubscribe.func.php))